# Where is complete() defined in Jake tasks?

Tags: jake

My editor is complaining that `complete()` is undefined in a `task`.

Where is it defined? Can I do something like this?

```
const { task, exec } = require('jake')
task('default', () => {
  exec(..., () => this.complete())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const jake = require('jake')
...
task('default', () => {
  exec(..., () => jake.complete())
```

The above will work